# Is it possible to undo an upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, samba

I had a server running 16.04 all was well and I didn't really need to upgrade it. I foolishly did so and now lot sof things have broken, most importantly the Windows share functionality doesn't work on in 18.04. Is it possible to roll back the upgrade?

Comment: Downgrading is possible for skilled users, but it is not supported by apt (or us) due to the many possible complications. The recommended method of downgrading is to backup data and settings, then to clean-install the older version of Ubuntu...unless, of course, you have versioned full backups you can roll back to.

Comment: It's a real shame, Ubuntu server used to be so much better that 18.04. Definitely a step in the wrong direction. Oh well, thanks for your response user535733